# How can I create an alert for when the close price crosses/hits a value that is line.new function?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to create an alert that will active whenever the close price cross or hit the trendline. This is the trendline code:

```
//Declaration of trendline function
a_f_trendline(a__input_function, a__delay, a__only_up, a__extend) =>
//Calculate line coordinates (Ax,Ay) - (Bx,By)
var int a_Ax = 1
var int a_Bx = 1
var float a_By = 0
var float a_slope = 0
a_Ay = fixnan(a__input_function)
if ta.change(a_Ay) != 0
a_Ax := time[a__delay]
a_By := a_Ay[1]
a_Bx := a_Ax[1]
a_slope := log_chart ? (math.log(a_Ay) - math.log(a_By)) / (a_Ax - a_Bx) : (a_Ay - a_By) / (a_Ax - a_Bx)
a_slope
else
a_Ax := a_Ax[1]
a_Bx := a_Bx[1]
a_By := a_By[1]
a_By
//Draw trendlines
var line a_trendline = na
var int a_Axbis = 0
var float a_Aybis = 0
var bool a__xtend = true
a_extension_time = a_Extension_Multiplier * a_bar_time * 25
a_Axbis := a_Ax + a_extension_time
a_Aybis := log_chart ? a_Ay * math.exp(a_extension_time * a_slope) : a_Ay + a_extension_time * a_slope
if a_Extension_Multiplier != 0
a__xtend := false
a__xtend
if ta.change(a_Ay) != 0

a_line_color_Rising_Falling = a_slope * time < 0 ? a__only_up ? a_Rising_Upper_Falling_Lower ? a_Color_Type == 'Colored' ? color.gray : color.teal : na : a_Color_Type == 'Colored' ? #cf0a83 : color.teal : a__only_up ? a_Color_Type == 'Colored' ? #027521 : color.teal : a_Rising_Upper_Falling_Lower ? a_Color_Type == 'Colored' ? color.gray : color.teal : na
a_line_color_Not_Rising_Falling = a_slope * time < 0 ? a__only_up ? na : a_Color_Type == 'Colored' ? #cf0a83 : color.teal : a__only_up ? a_Color_Type == 'Colored' ? #027521 : color.teal : na

a_line_color = a_Show_Primary and not a_Rising_Upper_Falling_Lower ? a_line_color_Not_Rising_Falling : a_Show_Primary and a_Rising_Upper_Falling_Lower ? a_line_color_Rising_Falling : na

if not na(a_line_color)
a_trendline = line.new(a_Bx, a_By, a_Axbis, a_Aybis, xloc.bar_time, extend=a__xtend ? extend.right : extend.none, color=a_line_color, style=line.style_solid, width=a_width)
a_trendline
[a_Bx, a_By, a_Axbis, a_Aybis, a_slope,a_trendline]

//Calculate pivot points    
a_high_point = ta.pivothigh(c > o ? c : o, a_len, a_len / 2)
a_low_point = ta.pivotlow(c > o ? o : c, a_len, a_len / 2)

//Call trendline function for high and low pivot points
[a_phx1, a_phy1, a_phx2, a_phy2, a_slope_high,a_trendline_high] = a_f_trendline(a_high_point, a_len / 2, false, true)
[a_plx1, a_ply1, a_plx2, a_ply2, a_slope_low,a_trendline_low] = a_f_trendline(a_low_point, a_len / 2, true, true)
```

I got a line value a_trendline_high and a_trendline_low.

How can I create an alert that will alert me whenever the close price crosses/hits the trendlines?

I try to do this:

```
upperYvalue = line.get_y1(a_trendline_high)
bool newCrossUp = c[1] < upperYvalue and c > upperYvalue
bool newCrossDn = c[1] > upperYvalue and c < upperYvalue
plotshape(newCrossUp , title="Cross Above", color=color.green, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.absolute)
plotshape(newCrossDn , title="Cross Below", color=color.red, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.absolute)
```

But the plotshape is created for every bar.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.